# Add number to random item in a list loop problem

Tags: python, loops

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bQWnO.jpg)This simple method should with every loop add number to random item in a list, but after the process, I got sum bigger or smaller than I did loops when adding +1. Here is my code and printscreen.
Thank you for help in advance.

```
looplength = 20
inputlist = [0,0,0,0,0]

import random

def addrandom(n):
    n[random.choice(range(len(n)))] += 1


for x in range(b):
    addrandom(a)


OUT = a
```

EXMPLES

> ```
> desired effect example:
>     input list = [0,0,0,0]
>     looplength = 20
>     result = [5,6,4,5]    
>     sum(result) = looplength
>
> actual example:
>     input list = [0,0,0,0]
>     looplength = 20
>     result = [5,6,6,5]    
>     sum(result) =! looplength
> ```

Comment: The desired and actual example results are identical...?

Comment: No,  sum(result) should be equal to loop length but its not

Comment: Where are `a` and `b` coming from?

Comment: I can't reproduce your results (the output is as expected). Show the rest of your code (including how `OUT` is used and the values of `a, b`).

Comment: Can you show us the output of an actual run of the code? I don't see why `sum(result)` shouldn't give you 20.

Comment: Out should be just a list like input zero list,  but with some positive numbers with sum is equal to loop number, that's all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at the code-snippet below:

```
import random


def addrandom(lst, n):
    for _ in range(n):
        lst[random.choice(range(len(lst)))] += 1
    return lst

looplength = 20
inputlist  = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]

res = addrandom(inputlist, looplength)
```

which produces:

```
print(res)  # -> [5, 3, 3, 6, 3]
```

As it can be seen from this run, it does indeed result in a list which elements sum up to `looplength` (5 + 3 + 3 + 6 + 3 = 20)

---

Your code is a bit *unorthodox* in my humble opinion.

- Instead of calling the function in every loop, why not have the loop inside the function?
- Secondly, by not returning anything you are counting on the list being changed in-place, which only adds confusion to the reader.